# Sort an array based on values from another array of different length

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've looked through several posts with similar with issues but I couldn't find one which solves my problem. The others all seemed to be sorting using another array of the same size or by value.

I have two arrays which look like this:

```
var allCategories = ['Campus', 'Building', 'Floor', 'Room', 'Lecture Theatre', 'Lab'];
var currentCategories = ['Room', 'Lab', 'Campus'];
```

How can I sort `currentCategories` so that the order matches that of `allCategories`?

**Desired output:**

```
currentCategories --> ['Campus', 'Room', 'Lab'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sort this array by the indices of its elements in that array":

```
currentCategories.sort(function(a, b) {
  return allCategories.indexOf(a) - allCategories.indexOf(b);
});
// => ["Campus", "Room", "Lab"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If all that you want is the *order* of `allCategories` with the members of `currentCategories`, you can do the following.

```
allCategories.filter(function(x){return currentCategories.indexOf(x) != -1})
```

This assumes that you are treating each `array` as a set of non-repeating elements. As mentioned in the comments, this method *may* drop duplicate elements from the final value, or not order duplicate elements in the way you might intend.

Comment: Faster but fails on duplicates. (+1 anyway :D ) (EDIT: not a complaint; in OP's use case there probably aren't any duplicates. But caveat emptor and all that)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the +1. I am not sure I would say that it fails on duplicate values, but rather that sorting an `array` of values by the ordering defined in a second `array` produces undefined results if a given value occurs more than once in the ordering `array`. I mean, if `x` appears at index `1` and `5` in the ordering array, how do we order it in the primary array (`currentCategories` in this case). Is it after the values at indices < `5` or before the values at indices > `1`?

Comment: What I meant is, if the array-to-be-sorted were to be `['Room', 'Lab', 'Campus', 'Room']`, you would sort a four-element list into a three-element one.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the input. I didn't think you were complaining, I just didn't see the length edge case at first.

Comment: @Amadan you are correct. There are no duplicate values.

Comment: @isomarcte +1 it works just fine but I'll go with Amadan's answer because I didn't mention in the question that were no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Array.Sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method can be supplied a custom function. You could do something like this:

```
currentCategories.sort(function(a, b) {
    var i = allCategories.indexOf(a),
        j = allCategories.indexOf(b);           
    return i - j;
});
```

I haven't checked the behaviour for when there are values in `currentCategories` that are not in `allCategories`. But then, it wouldn't be living up to its name if that were the case.

If this is a common case, you could generalise it along the following lines:

```
function sortByList(list) {
    return function (a, b) { return list.indexOf(a) - list.indexOf(b); };
}
```

And call it thusly:

```
currentCategories.sort(sortByList(allCategories));
```